# Disable "keep using this file" suggestion screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-extension

From time to time Windows 10 "thinks" that I changed my mind and that there is a possibility that I would like to change default program that opens certain files in my computer:

[image]

This drives me nuts. I can't count how many times I checked "*Always use this app to open XXX files*" checkbox and how many times I clicked "*OK*" button, but this screen keeps appearing, over and over again, after few days, for the same extension or file type.

Is there any way to permanently tell Windows 10 that I want to use program X to open files with Y extension or to disable this kind of screens from appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to *permanently* prevent Windows from changing file associations without disabling all updates, AFAIK. However, by exporting the Registry key for these, in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\

they can be imported after MS mangles them.

[image: Registry File Exts showing .cab opens with 7-Zip]

Note that this contains *all* file extensions -- it would be best to edit the .reg file to remove the great majority, keeping just the keys you wish restored *après le déluge*.

N.B. This answer is perhaps a [duplicate of @Michael Goldshteyn's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings)... please let me know, and I'll remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer! No, I don't think that you can consider it a duplicate, if it is the only answer to this question and if it "duplicates" an answer given to a whole new question. You can have the same answer answering a lot of different questions, right? :>